# Best windows server administration tools

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best windows server administration tools](https://serverfault.com/questions/221507/best-windows-server-administration-tools)

Hi all,

I'm looking for the must-have tools to administrate a windows server (please don't mention sysinternals). Some examples of the information I'm looking for:

- list of shares with corresponding disk space usage
- list of users and their group memberships
- tweaking options to improve server's performance

Comment: Dupe of a dupe!

Answer (score 3):

A good set of books on administer Windows systems will go much further than the latest set of toys.

Comment: yea, but ...toys !